# Selection: Median of medians

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

As a homework I was assigned to write algorithm that finds k-th ordered number from unordered set of numbers. As an approach, algorithm `median of medians` has been presented.

Unfortunately, my attemp has failed. If anyone spots a mistake - please correct me.

```
private int find(int[] A, int size, int k) {
    if (size <= 10) {
        sort(A, 0, size);
        return A[k];
    } else {
        int[] M = new int[size/5];
        for (int i = 0; i < size / 5; i++) {
            sort(A, i*5, (i+1) * 5);
            M[i] = A[i*5 + 2];
        }

        int m = find(M, M.length, M.length / 2);

        int[] aMinus = new int[size];
        int aMinusIndex = 0;
        int[] aEqual = new int[size];
        int aEqualIndex = 0;
        int[] aPlus = new int[size];
        int aPlusIndex = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (A[j] < m) {
                aMinus[aMinusIndex++] = A[j];
            } else if (A[j] == m) {
                aEqual[aEqualIndex++] = A[j];
            } else {
                aPlus[aPlusIndex++] = A[j];
            }
        }

        if (aMinusIndex <= k) {
            return find(aMinus, aMinusIndex, k);
        } else if (aMinusIndex + aEqualIndex <= k) {
            return m;
        } else {
            return find(aPlus, aPlusIndex, k - aMinusIndex - aEqualIndex);
        }
    }
}

private void sort(int[] t, int begin, int end) { //simple insertion sort
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        int j = i;
        int element = t[i];
        while ((j > begin) && (t[j - 1] > element)) {
            t[j] = t[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        t[j] = element;
    }
}
```

The test I'm running is to put numbers {200, 199, 198, ..., 1) and get 1st number from ordered array. I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -13
```

Which is thrown at `return A[k]` line, because of recursive call:

```
return find(aPlus, aPlusIndex, k - aMinusIndex - aEqualIndex);
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your code under debugger?

Comment: are you sure both of your input and output relation to m?

Answer (score 2):

Your branching logic for the recursion step is backwards. You're trying to find the kth smallest number, and you've found that there are aMinusIndex numbers smaller than m, aEqualIndex equal to m, and aPlusIndex larger than m.

You should be searching in aMinus if aMinusIndex >= k, not if aMinusIndex <= k -- and so on.

(See this easily by looking at the extreme case: say there are zero numbers smaller than m. Then clearly you should not be searching for anything in an empty array, but because 0 <= k, you will be.)

Comment: You are right about the conditions. With the change however, I end up with strange results for e.g. 8th, 13th, ... number, for which algorithm returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your problem is, but you definitely should *not* be doing this:

```
sort(A, i*5, (i+1) * 5);
```

Also, you shouldn't do so much copying, you don't gain any performance when you do that. The algorithm is supposed to be done in place.

Check this wikipedia: [Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm)

Comment: Why should I not sort the subarrays?
I cant see any recursion in the algorithm on wikipedia. I would appreciate a proposition how to avoid the copying cause I must admit it produces quite big load.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is homework, so your options might be constrained, but I don't see how the Median of Medians is all that useful here.  Just sort the entire array using a standard algorithm, and pick the kth element.  Median of medians helps find a very good pivot for the sort.  For data of 200 length, you aren't going to save much time.

So far as I know, you can't *accurately* obtain a median, or a percentile, or the kth element, without ultimately sorting the entire input array.  Using subsets yields an *estimate*.  If this is wrong, I'd really like to know, as I recently worked on code to find percentiles in arrays of millions of numbers!

p.s. it could be that I don't completely understand your code...

Comment: Sorting is asymptotically slower than this algorithm, leaving aside implementation questions.

Comment: @tmykebu  Do you have a good reference to this M of M algorithm?  I'd like to know more about it.  Thanks.  BTW, the ]Wikipedia article I found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_) supports me: "Although this approach optimizes quite well, it is typically outperformed in practice by the expected linear algorithm with random pivot choices[citation needed]."

Comment: @user93400: It's in CLRS.  Yes, random sampling will do much better.  However, this median-of-medians trick still vastly outperforms sorting.